# Track usage of Permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I would like to know what applications use permissions like GPS, reading storage, accessing contacts, using camera, microphone. If possible can i make a dialog appear asking my consent before that app actually accesses the resources?
Is it possible to create an Android app like that?
Please guide me. I am very new to Android programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is No. You cannot restrict other apps.
But Since Android 6.0 users can manager their own apps permissions. look at to [this_link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6270602?hl=en). any question?

Comment: Thanks Joe! Is it possible to give the app Device Admin privilege so that all requests go through my app before accessing the resource? Will it work then?

Comment: You are welcome bro, I cannot say it is technically impossible, but not by an Android application, Android does not provide any API for this purpose. You have to deal with Linux programming -if it's possible-. And about the privilege, the default user for Android OS is not admin, unless you root the device and act as an admin. So giving privilege to an non-admin user is meaningless.
And take a look at Android architecture:
[this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/images/architecture.jpg)